# "Could not construct Closed Type using the provided arguments" error creating a generic list in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell script where I would like to create a generic List of a type that is defined in a custom (C++/CLI) assembly.

If I run `new-object My.Namespace.MyClass`, I can create objects all day.  However, if I run `new-genericobject System.Collections.Generic.List -Of My.Namespace.MyClass`, I get the below error:

```
New-GenericObject : Could not construct Closed Type using the provided arguments.
At line:1 char:18
+ new-genericobject <<<<  System.Collections.Generic.List -Of My.Namespace.MyClass
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-GenericObject], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Pscx.Commands.NewGenericObjectCommand
```

I can create lists of strings, so the basic functionality of new-genericobject is fine.  Does anyone have ideas on what this error means and how it can be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really like this solution, but it is the only thing I've found to work:

```
function CreateGenericList
{
    $dummy = New-Object My.Namespace.MyClass
    $generic = [System.Collections.Generic.List``1]
    $gt = $generic.MakeGenericType(@($dummy.GetType()))
    ,[Activator]::CreateInstance($gt)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this instead:

```
$list = new-object 'collections.generic.list[my.namespace.myclass]'
```

btw, what version of powershell are you using? what operating system?

**Update**

This might be a long running bug where if the element type is in a third party assembly and the collection is not in the same assembly, you must fully qualify the element type. Try this:

```
$list = new-object ("collections.generic.list[[{0}]]" `
    -f [MyClass].AssemblyQualifiedName)
```

Comment: That results in the below error:  

    `New-Object : Cannot find type [system.collections.generic.list[My.Namespace.MyClass]]: make sure the assembly containing this type is loaded.
    At line:1 char:11
    + new-object <<<<  'system.collections.generic.list[My.Namespace.MyClass]'
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand`  

This is using Powershell version 2.0 on WinXP SP3.

Comment: Ah, I think this is a long existing bug in powershell where if the element type is in a different assembly than the collection and it is not part of the BCL, you must use a fully qualified type name. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Hmm, I can't seem to get that to work no matter what.  I tried several variations of that approach (your approach, using it without the formatted string, etc) and I always get the above error about making sure the assembly is loaded.  After doing some Googling, I found the below approach which does work but is rather verbose: `function CreateGenericList
{
    $dummy = New-Object My.Namespace.MyClass
    $generic = [System.Collections.Generic.List``1]
    $gt = $base.MakeGenericType(@($dummy.GetType()))
    ,[Activator]::CreateInstance($gt)
}`